# Logger should be defined private static final and have the correct class

Tags: java, logging, pmd

I have the below line of code for logging.

`private static final Log LOGGER_MESSAGE = LogFactory.getLog(CandidateDAOImpl.class);`

the PMD throws

`Logger should be defined private static final and have the correct class`

I am using private final static variable and my file name is CandidateDAOImpl.

Any ideas why it's behaving like this?

Comment: Is there any error if you use `CandidateDAOImp.class.getName()` as a parameter?

Comment: Side note on wording: why are you naming something that is of class Log; and seems to be used as "logging facility" ... LOGGER_MESSAGE?! That name implies something else than what it seems to be.

Comment: yes @DmitryGinzburg, i get a error saying "The method getLog(Class<?>) in the type LogFactory is not applicable for the arguments (String) "

Comment: @Jägermeister , It is final static variable.. so aren't we suppose to use capitals?

Comment: @SakethKotha OK then, what is the library you use to log and which version are you using?

Comment: @SakethKotha it's not about the case, but about name of variable.

Comment: please post declaration your CandidateDAOImpl class

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg i am using Log4j2

Comment: @alexs       public class CandidateDAOImpl implements CandidateDAO

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg .. sure thing... 'll change the name

Comment: @SakethKotha post a **complete**, minimal example reproducing the problem. We can't do anything with just one line of code, out of context.

Comment: @SakethKotha As Dmitry said, it is about the term MESSAGE in there. Besides: **never** provide additional information in comments, **always update** your question instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of your variable name `LOGGER_MESSAGE`. The PMD rule **ProperLogger** default log name is `LOG`. See http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/rules/logging-jakarta-commons.html

However, it's not properly documented and the error message is quite misleading.

Add below to your PMD config file should fix the problem:

```
<rule 
  ref="rulesets/java/logging-jakarta-commons.xml/ProperLogger">
    <properties>
        <property name="staticLoggerName" value="LOGGER_MESSAGE"/>
    </properties>
</rule>
```

Also the same idea, if someone want to change the 'LOG' to 'log', you need to update the `staticLoggerName` property